# Как изменится матрица перехода от одного базиса к другому?

Tags: линейная-алгебра

Как изменится матрица перехода от одного базиса к другому, если:

а) поменять местами два вектора первого базиса

б) поменять местами два вектора второго базиса

в) записать векторы обоих базисов в обратном порядке?

Я понимаю, как именно изменится матрица, но как это можно доказать?
(Работу я саму уже сдала, где было это задание, там не было необходимости приводить доказательство, это чисто мой интерес)

Answer (score 1):

Как получается матрица перехода? Наверное, примерно так с использованием инверсной матрицы, образованной из матрицы векторов первого базиса:

```
 {x1 x2 x3}          {X1 X2 X3}
 {y1 y2 y3}  x  M =  {Y1 Y2 Y3}
 {z1 z2 z3}          {Z1 Z2 Z3}
     
     b       x  M =     B
  inv(b) x b x  M  = inv(b) * B
        I    x  M  = inv(b) * B

  M = inv(b) * B
```

Вот и смотрите, что будет с последней формулой при указанных изменениях базисов.